# Access Query: Average per Entry

Tags: ms-access

[image]

Here's a little background on what I'm trying to do.
[All_Distributors] is a list of products and product info.
[Brand_Volume_Conversion] is a list of products Ive measured and weighed for shipping purposes, which allowed me to calculate a Volume per lb for each item.  I would like to use this volume per lb measurement to help me predict the volume of a product based on Brand and similar weighted items.
This is what I have so far (image) but Im getting Duplicate entries per given Part Number and its taking forever to do so. Im kind of stuck at this point, I thought someone else might have a better way of doing this or have some suggestions for a newby.  Thanks for the help.

Ive made a little head way since I asked this question.  I have now got the results Im after, however its still very slow.  Between the 500,000 records in [All_Distributors] and another 7,000 [Brand_Volume_Conversion] it creeps and unusable.  Anyone have any suggestions? Second picture is of working but slow code.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with your first version of the query, but with the following changes:

1. Use Brand as the related column between the two tables (i.e. the line)
2. Make it a "Totals" query but clicking the sigma in the ribbon at the top
3. Set the "Total" property for your Distributer+Partnum,Brand and Weight columns in the grid to "Group By"
4. Add your "Distributor_Weight" column to the query grid; set its "Total" property to "Where"
5. Set this new entry's "Criteria" property to ">=[Weight]*.9 And <=[Weight]*1.1"
6. Change your Vol/lb to "Vol/lb: [Volume per lb]" and set its "Total" property to "Average"

The idea here is to avoid using the sub-query in your calculation. That's what's really slowing things down. Also, I'm a little confused your multiplying by -1 twice and am assuming that matching on Brand is what you want.